# getting FileNotFound Exception when copying remote files to local Folder

Tags: java, jsch

I am using the following code, when i am trying to write the files to my local folder i am getting the Access is denied error to the Local folder.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")             
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list =      sftpChannel.ls("Orders");
for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry listEntry : list) 
{  
 String SourceFileName=listEntry.getFilename();
 if(SourceFileName.startsWith("O") || SourceFileName.endsWith(".XML"))
{
 System.out.println("SourceFileName="+SourceFileName);  
 sftpChannel.get(SourceFileName,new FileOutputStream(f));
}   
}
```

Comment: Did you check the access rights of your local folder?

Comment: Yes @Sandy its not Read only its ready for archiving

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `FileOutputStream` you have to specify a file, not a folder. If `f` contains a `File` instance representing your target folder and `SourceFileName` is a simple name without directory parts, you can use `new FileOutputStream(new File(f, SourceFileName))` to create a target stream.